# Как работает QScrollArea?

Tags: python, python-3.x, qt, pyqt5, pyqt

Объясните, пожалуйста, как можно работать со `QScrollArea`. В дизайнере сделал, но не работает. В интернете нормальных решений не нашел

Comment: Ну, ScrollArea это виджет-контейнер для виджетов, чей размер обычно очень большой и чтобы окно с ними умещалось, добавляется скролл-бары (ползунки). А в чем у вас проблема?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[QScrollArea](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qscrollarea.html) это виджет-контейнер для виджетов, чей размер обычно очень большой и чтобы окно с ними умещалось, добавляются скролл-бары (ползунки).

Для помещения виджетов в `QScrollArea` нужен не `layout` (компоновщик), а виджет, поэтому у нее есть метод `setWidget`.

Например этот код создаст большое количество кнопок:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QGridLayout, QPushButton, QWidget, QScrollArea


app = QApplication([])

layout = QGridLayout()
for i in range(10):
    for j in range(5):
        button = QPushButton(f'{i}x{j}')
        layout.addWidget(button, i, j)

w = QWidget()
w.setLayout(layout)

mw = QScrollArea()
mw.setWidget(w)
mw.resize(200, 200)
mw.show()

app.exec()
```

Окно будет выглядеть так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При увеличении размера окна ползунки исчезнут:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

`QScrollArea` может менять размер виджетов в ней, растягивать их. За это отвечает свойство [widgetResizable](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qscrollarea.html#widgetResizable-prop), которое по умолчанию `False`.

Если у `QScrollArea` это свойство активировать (`mw.setWidgetResizable(True)`), то виджеты в ней растянутся:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: получается, layout нужен обязательно?

Comment: Добавил в ответ: `Для помещения виджетов в QScrollArea нужен не `layout` (компоновщик), а виджет, поэтому у нее есть метод setWidget.`